# How to print pascal triangle using python

Tags: python

Code is below

```
def pascal(p):
    res = [[0 for i in range(p)] for i in range(p)]
    for i in range(p):
        res.append((11**i))
    return res
p= 3
pascal(p)
```

My out is
`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], 1, 11, 121]`

Expected is

`[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]]`

pascal's triangle is multiplication of 11, will split() method will work here

Comment: What is your question exactly? Can you please phrase it clearly, and also note that homework assignments are not permitted on Stack Overflow :).

Comment: @jlengrand [Feelings about them are mixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), but there's no rule against them.

Comment: Alright noted, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You

- don't need the array initialization
- you need to build a value padded with zeros until the size of `p`
- split string on each char => `list('abcd') == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

```
def pascal(p):
    res = []
    for i in range(p):
        row = str(11 ** i).ljust(p, '0')
        res.append(list(row))
    return res

print(pascal(3))  
# [['1', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '2', '1']]
print(pascal(6))
# [['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
#  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
#  ['1', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
#  ['1', '3', '3', '1', '0', '0'],
#  ['1', '4', '6', '4', '1', '0'],
#  ['1', '6', '1', '0', '5', '1']]
```

---

The list-comprehension equivalent

```
def pascal(p):
    return [list(str(11 ** i).ljust(p, '0')) for i in range(p)]
```

Comment: You could also fill in the extra zeroes with [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust): `str(11 ** i).ljust(p, '0')`

Comment: @CrazyChucky never needed that, didn't even know the method , nice :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not all in one comprehension by computing the number then turning it into a string justifying it by `p` then mapping `int` to it:

```
def pascal(p):
    return [list(map(int, str(11**i).ljust(p, '0'))) for i in range(p)]
```

---

```
>>> pascal(3)
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]]
>>> pascal(9)
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 6, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 7, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0], [1, 9, 4, 8, 7, 1, 7, 1, 0], [2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to generate empty arrays

```
def pascal(p):
    res = []
    for i in range(p):
        l = [int(d) for d in str(11 ** i)]
        l += [0] * (p - len(l))
        res.append(l) #append variable 
    return res

p = 3
print(pascal(p))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]]
```